# Foundation E-mail: Image over 2 rows

Tags: email, frameworks, zurb-foundation, html-email, responsive

I am making a custom responsive e-mail by the use of Foundation Framework. I want to achieve the lay-out as shown in the screenshot. Any advice on how to implement this, using Foundation (or wether this will be even possible? keeping in mind that is should work in ALL major mailclients)

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We cannot build you the whole solution here. Try working on it and if your stuck in some place in your code then we can help there but dont expect people to sit and spend time to work from scratch to give you ready build solutions. Share your code if you have done something and are having problem with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a HTML solution then below is the code you can use.

Its rough but gives an idea using your visual.

```html
<table width="600" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#17b0de" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight:bold; padding:47px 0px; text-align:center; font-size:80px;color:#ffffff;">ROW 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="55" height="190" bgcolor="#17b0de">&nbsp;</td>
        <td bgcolor="#49267c" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight:bold;  text-align:center; font-size:80px;color:#ffffff;">VISUAL</td>
        <td width="55" bgcolor="#17b0de">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
          <td width="55" height="79" bgcolor="#d9ecf2">&nbsp;</td>
          <td bgcolor="#49267c" style="height:10px;line-height:0px; font-size:0px;"></td>
          <td width="55" bgcolor="#d9ecf2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#d9ecf2" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight:bold; padding:20px 0px; text-align:center; font-size:80px;color:#ffffff;">ROW 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It's totally possible although not super trivial. You can build something similar by using a background color on a section above, and the same color horizontally where the visual is.

```
<row>
<row><img></row>
<row>
```

Example:
https://codepen.io/rafibomb/pen/oeEMbO

[image]

[image]